autostart VPN connection by systemd
I want to automatically start vpn connection after login as one of my users. I can not use Network Manager, because the server is using incompatible settings. I want to start it just for one of my user. I created shell script, which works fine. Than I created in /etc/systemd/user file my_vpn.service, with this input:
[Unit]
Description=my_vpn
After=network-online.target

[Service]
StartLimitIntervalSec=1
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
ExecStart=/home/my/.ssh/.vpn_connect

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

When I start service, it works fine. But when I enable it and restart computer, I get
systemctl --user status my_vpn.service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/xdg/systemd/user/my_vpn.service; enabled; vendo>
Active: inactive (dead)

Could you pls help me, how to debug it?
